# Number of elements of induced permutation group Ĝ.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let's say we have a permutation group $G$ acting on a finite set $D$, and a finite set $R$ of colours. We can induce a permutation group $\hat{G}$ acting on $R^{D}$ (where $R^D$ is the set of functions from $R$ to $D$), by defining for any $\sigma \in G$, the function $\hat{\sigma}$ is defined by:

$$\hat{\sigma}: R^D \longrightarrow R^D :  F \longmapsto \hat{\sigma}(F)$$

such that:

$$\forall d \in D: \hat{\sigma}(F)(d) = F(\sigma(d))$$

Now my question is, is there a relation between $\lvert G \rvert$ and $\lvert \hat{G} \rvert$? I first thought that we simply had $\lvert \hat{G} \rvert$ = $\lvert G \rvert$. However, if we have, let's say:

$D = \{1,2,3,4\}$,

$\sigma_1 = (1)$, $\sigma_2 = (1 \, 2)(3 \, 4)$, and

$F(1) = F(2) = b$, $F(3) = F(4) = w$,

then $\hat{\sigma}_1 = \sigma_1(F)$, and $\hat{\sigma}_2 = \sigma_2(F)$. And at the same time, $\hat{\sigma}_1 = \hat{\sigma}_2$. So two different permutations in $G$ yield the same in $\hat{G}$. Am I missing something here? Is there another relation between $\lvert G \rvert$ and $\lvert \hat{G} \rvert$?

Edit: I think I know what I did wrong. To show that $\hat{\sigma}_1 =\hat{\sigma}_2$, I need to show that $\hat{\sigma}_1(F) = \hat{\sigma}_2(F) \, \, \forall F \in R^D$, and not $\forall d \in D$ and a fixed $F$. Still, I don't know if $\lvert G \rvert = \lvert \hat{G} \rvert$.

Edit2: I think I found it. It's obvious that $\lvert G \rvert \geq \lvert \hat{G} \rvert$. Now I just need to show the other way around. And if I take two differnt $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, i.e.:

$\exists x,y_1,y_2 \in D: \sigma_1(x) = y_1, \sigma_2(x) = y_2, y1 \neq y2$

Then I just choose a colouring $F(y_1) = b$ and $F(y_2) = w$ and so $\lvert G \rvert \leq \lvert \hat{G} \rvert$, hence $\lvert G \rvert = \lvert \hat{G} \rvert$. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both your analysis of your original mistake and the fix for it are correct.

The codomain of $\hat\sigma$ should be $R^D$, not $R$.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Since it sends one function to another. Thanks a lot.